# How to subset a large data frame for faster execution?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have a large data set loaded into a data frame.

```
tbl = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="db", 
    table_name="tbl"
)
```

I'm working on this data experimentally in a Jupyter Notebook talking to a Glue/Spark endpoint.

So, a lot of commands are not required to run on the full data but a small subset is sufficient.

So I tried this f.x.:

```
tbls = tbl.toDF().randomSplit([0.01,199.9], 42)
```

But working on the the small subset `tbls[0]` doesn't seem to be significantly more performant.

```
a = time.time()
cnt = oivvs[0].count()
b = time.time()
print(f"cnt = {cnt} / {b-a} sec")

-> cnt = 2252 / 72.31371855735779 sec

a = time.time()
cnt = oivvs[1].count()
b = time.time()
print(f"cnt = {cnt} / {b-a} sec")

-> cnt = 45578867 / 77.46211075782776 sec
```

I suspect the reason is related to lazy evaluation of the expressions. I guess the goal is to create a deep copy then.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the limit function? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=limit#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit

Comment: @Raffael, you are still reading the entire data from table into dynamicframe "tbl" in the first step. Limiting the data in first step should be a better way to increase the performance. Dynamic frame may not allow you to load data directly from SQL, you can instead try dataframe.